# How to initialize multiple application variables in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hi I need to know how to initialize multiple application variables in angularjs..

Here what I have done..

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John'" ng-init="secName='Carter'">
    <div>
        Name is 
    <div ng-bind="firstName +' ' + secName"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But I can't get the correct output of "**John Carter**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do it like this,

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John';secName='Carter'">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a scope function in `ng-init`

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-init="initialise()">
    ...
</div>
```

In your corresponding controller, you can initialise all your scope variables.

```
$scope.initialise = function() {
   $scope.firstName = 'John';
   $scope.secName = 'Carter';
}
```